# "Crc32" не содержит содержимое для "Compute"

Tags: c#, .net, консоль, crc

Мне надо высчитать контроль суммы для команды при помощи Crc32 а я эта делаю в первый раз и нашёл код:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(arrCommand);
UInt32 hash = Crc32.Compute(bytes);
Console.WriteLine("CRC-32 is {0}", hash);
```

и мне пришит ошибку и не могу понять в чём дело, гуглить пробовал ничего не нашёл но эта я слепой.

Ошибка:

> "Crc32" не содержит содержимое для "Compute"

помогите понять в чём дело

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так получится.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(arrCommand);
byte[] hash = Crc32.Hash(bytes);
uint crc = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt32LittleEndian(hash);
Console.WriteLine("CRC-32 is {0}", crc);
```

[Crc32](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.hashing.crc32) класс доступен для .NET 6 и 7 в NuGet пакете [System.IO.Hashing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Hashing/).