# Как корректно записать Cardinal из Delphi (он же unsigned int из C++) в C#?

Tags: c#, delphi

Есть строка из delphi:

```
      var Mask: Cardinal;
      Mask := -(Result and 1);
      Result := (Result shr 1) xor (Mask and $FF242143);
```

При написании её в C#:

```
      uint mask;
      uint result = 0;
      mask = -(result & 1);
      result = (result>>1) ^ (mask & 0xFF242143);
```

Выводит ошибку:

> Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "long" в "uint". Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов)

Comment: Если что, в .NET [есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1477598/373567) библиотеки с уже готовыми быстрыми реализациями CRC32, вплоть до аппаратного ускорения и векторных вычислений, а так есть еще [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1326402/373567).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cardinal` из Delphi это по сути `uint` в C#.

- `int` и `uint` в C# - 4-байтовые целые числа
- `long` и `ulong` - 8-байтовые

Вы пытаетесь привести 8-байтовое число со знаком к 4-байтовому числу без знака. Так как такой каст может повлечь за собой частичную потерю данных, его нельзя выполнять неявно. Но можно кастануть явно поставив `(uint)` перед переменной.

Так как `uint` беззнаковое целое, при попытке изменить ему знак, C# подбирает наиболее подходящий тип с неявным приведением, в данном случае `long`.

На мой взгляд, стоит избежать каста к 8-байтовым типам, чтобы не нарушить двоичную логику. А так же закастовать результат обратно в `uint`.

```cs
uint result = 0;
uint mask = (uint)-((int)result & 1); // если навести мышку на оператор &, студия покажет, для каких типов он выполнится.
result = (result >> 1) ^ (mask & 0xFF242143);
```